# magento extension is installed in backend but not visible on frontend

Tags: magento

I had installed a magento extension for cashu payment gateway.Earlier I could see it on the backend as well as on the frontend. Later I uninstalled it. Cashu support team gave me correct version of extension to install it manually. But this time I could see the extension only in the backend but not in frontend. What could be the possible reason for this and how do I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: cache ? compilation ? was the uninstallation complete ? the module activated and visible ?

Comment: yes..i cleared the cache and the compilation was also disabled..Uninstallation was complete as well..